# List of Installed apps force closes : java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, performance

I am trying to make an app which gives the list of installed apps and when an item is clicked , starts another activity which states the permissions required by installed apps. I got the installed application list, but when I click any app instead of starting new activity , the application force closes.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.appslist;

import java.util.List;
import com.example.appslist.adapter.ApkAdapter;
import com.example.appslist.app.AppData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class ApkListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    PackageManager packageManager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        ListView mylistview= (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mylistview.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList, packageManager));



        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long row) {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) parent
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
        AppData appData = (AppData) getApplicationContext();
        appData.setPackageInfo(packageInfo);

        Intent appInfo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApkInfo.class);
        startActivity(appInfo);
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
04-02 11:16:04.536: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.appslist === version 1
04-02 11:16:04.559: D/dalvikvm(2777): Trying to load lib lib_glossary.so 0x0
04-02 11:16:04.559: I/dalvikvm(2777): Unable to dlopen(lib_glossary.so): Cannot load library: load_library[1083]: Library 'lib_glossary.so' not found
04-02 11:16:04.567: E/MBGlossaryManager(2777): lib_glossary.so can't be loaded
04-02 11:16:04.700: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.708: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.708: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.708: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-02 11:16:04.715: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.723: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.arcsoft.photoworkshop === version 5
04-02 11:16:04.778: D/dalvikvm(2777): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 822 objects / 60704 bytes in 56ms
04-02 11:16:04.786: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.phone === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.794: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.calculator2 === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.794: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.htmlviewer === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.801: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.myfirstapp === version 1
04-02 11:16:04.801: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.providers.calendar === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.809: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.bluetooth === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.809: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.sessionmanagement === version 1
04-02 11:16:04.817: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.calendar === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.817: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.817: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.825: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-02 11:16:04.825: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-02 11:16:04.872: E/asset(2777): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-02 11:16:06.536: D/AndroidRuntime(2777): Shutting down VM
04-02 11:16:06.536: W/dalvikvm(2777): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207e0)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity.onItemClick(ApkListActivity.java:44)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3444)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-02 11:16:06.551: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 11:16:08.137: I/Process(2777): Sending signal. PID: 2777 SIG: 9
```

I cannot understand the reason for force closing. Please help

AppData.java

```
package com.example.appslist.app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;

public class AppData extends Application {

    PackageInfo packageInfo;

    public PackageInfo getPackageInfo() {
        return packageInfo;
    }

    public void setPackageInfo(PackageInfo packageInfo) {
        this.packageInfo = packageInfo;
    }
}
```

ApkAdapter.java

```
package com.example.appslist.adapter;

import java.util.List;
import com.example.appslist.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;

    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
            PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apklist_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appname);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);
        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Manifest File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appslist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
     >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ApkInfo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_apk_info" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what is that AppData class?

Comment: @ankita gahoi : I have added both classes used in main .check

Comment: try with this. http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android/

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys I was following that tutorial only , but I am getting errors as mentioned

Comment: let me try and tel you the probs.

Comment: @Prax Check my Edit, that should solve your problem

Comment: hi @Prax i have answered for your issue.. just check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

> It seems you have not registered AppData in the Manifest

Try to add

```
  android:name=".AppData"
```

in your Application tag of the Manifest.

i.e this

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".AppData"
         >
```

---

Error is in this line

```
 AppData appData = (AppData) getApplicationContext();
```

Change that to

```
AppData appData = (AppData) getApplication();
```

Comment: Ya I changed , still force closing on item click in the list :(

Comment: @Prax But you won't get the same error. This will fix your current issue

Comment: @Prax There might be new issue let me know

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting same errors in the logcat.I am confused what exactly is causing the force close !

Comment: @Prax is it solved your issue...? What happened when you tried this..? Let me know

Comment: @ Pragnani : No it dint help , as far as I know , only new activity needs to be added in the manifest, not all java classes ?

Comment: @Prax I have copied your code and tested.. and I am able to reproduce your issue and then when I register application in Manifest it is working. So that should solve your issue because I have tested with your code itself. May be you haven't check my edit. or please post your Manifest I'll show what to do

Comment: @Prax And also change your intent like this             **Intent appInfo = new Intent(ApkListActivity.this, ApkInfo.class);**  And also register class ***ApkInfo*** in your Manifest

Comment: Hey thanks I added as  android:name=".app.AppData" It worked , I couldnt get your point that time :)

Answer (score 1):

You define a new class named AppData, then how can you cast an object returned by getApplicationContext() which is not an instance of AppData to AppData?

For example,

```
class A{}

class B extends from A{}

class C extends from A{}

A foo(){
    return new C();
}

B b = (B)foo();
```

That will definitely cause classcastexception because an object with type C is not an instance of B.

I think you just need to send some information to the ApkInfo.class, so why don't you use bundle?

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("key", "data");   
bundle.putString("key2", "data2"); 
intent.setClass(...)
intent.putExtras(bundle); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Update:

Then you can get the information you stored in the target activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(...){
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    bundle.getString("key");
}
```

Comment: Can u explain in detail what exactly I should do , in this case ? I am new to Android. Thanks

Comment: I tried this, but it shows errors, I am still stuck up with this :(

Answer (score 0):

This is causing the issue:

`PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

you are trying to cast a different object to `PackageInfo` check for a different method that returns `PackageInfo` as return type to avoid this.

**Edit:**

Try,

`PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getClass().getPackage();`

instead , I just checked it for a view object.

Comment: It says "Cannot Cast from Package to PackageInfo"

Comment: then you have to look for some getter of `packageInfo`

Comment: @pKs That is not a problem...That is valid

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your manifest application file.

Please replace your below line with

```
 android:name="com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.AppData"
```

following line

```
android:name="com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.activity.AppData"
```

Hope this will help you.